# XML String convert into array in php

Tags: php

I convert xml string into array in php. But I generate bookstore array within only one book array and nested array which index is 0,1,2. I need same name (book) array into bookstore. how to generate this type of array.
The xml string is....

```
$string = "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bookstore>
    <book>
        <name>PHP</name>
        <author>W3School</author>
        <price>200</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <name>C#.Net</name>
        <author>Microsoft</author>
        <price>250</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <name>Asp.Net</name>
        <author>Microsoft</author>
        <price>350</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>";


$value = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($value);
```

In above code, i run and output display in book array in 0,1,2 index.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
     [book] => Array (  
                     [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                             [name] => PHP 
                             [author] => W3School 
                             [price] => 200 ) 
                     [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                             [name] => C#.Net 
                             [author] => Microsoft 
                             [price] => 250 ) 
                     [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                             [name] => Asp.Net  
                             [author] => Microsoft 
                             [price] => 350 ) 
                    ) )
```

But i need one array which name is bookstore and into nested array with multiple book array replace of [0],[1],[2].

Answer (score 0):

to convert SimpleXMLObject to array, you can use

> $value = json_decode(json_encode($value), TRUE);

About need of nested in `bookstore`, you simple need to do it manually.

> return ['bookstore' => $value];

After some much time, you maybe got other answer?